# Watin:Get date from textfield

Tags: c#, watin

I have a textfield that has a date with the format "12/23/2010".Is there away for me to get the number 23 using watin ie get number from textfield;i'm gonna use it like this.
1.Get datetime 12/23/2010 and get number '23'
2.substract 2 from 23 and store it somewhere[ie: 23 - 2 = 21] 
3.Insert the new datetime number [ie:12/21/2010 ]

```
    string myDate = browser.TextField(Find.ByName("myTextField")).Value;
    DateTime time =  = new DateTime();
    time2 = time - 2;
    browser.TextField(Find.ByName("myTextField")).TypeText(time2);
```

Is this possible?or should i be looking to another way.Ask the user to insert the data instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
string myDate = browser.TextField(Find.ByName("myTextField")).Value;
DateTime time =  = new DateTime();
if(DateTime.TryParse(myDate, out time);) {
     Console.WriteLine(time.Month);
}
else {
   //Not a valid date.
}
```